# How !(!A || B) should be simplified

Tags: logic

This is a first-year-of-university question but I just cannot get around it.

```
!(!A || B)
```

simplified is...?

I have tried

```
!(A || B) = !A && !B
```

So A = !A  ,   B = B

```
!!A && B = A && !B
```

But it does not work!!! any ideas?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, you can "expand" the not operator and get A && !B as a result.

Comment: Apparently the logic operation is correct but since it is a javascript expression, the! A

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about pure logic, boolean algebra, and [math.se] instead of directly about programming or software development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already did that correctly. What "does not work"?

`!(!A || B)` and `A && !B` are equivalent. You can verify that easily comparing the truth tables:

```
A  B  !A  !A || B  !(!A || B)
-  -  --  -------  ----------
0  0   1     1         0
0  1   1     1         0
1  0   0     0         1
1  1   0     1         0
```

and:

```
A  B  !B  A && !B
-  -  --  -------
0  0   1     0   
0  1   0     0   
1  0   1     1   
1  1   0     0
```

Same result.

Answer (score 5):

If you use the De Morgan laws you can simplify it very easy:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

The solution in this case would be A && !B

Answer (score 5):

In general:

```
!(A || B) = !A && !B
```

In your case, `A` "is"  `!A`, so you get:

```
!(!A || B) = !(!A) && !B = A && !B
```

Comment: I think the problem is more related to javascript null expression checking, since.! A also means A is null. Thank to all of you